# ''Ticker'' in list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand this section of the code in which "ticker" gets used in a list comprehension. Can anyone tell me what "ticker" means and where it came from. I'll include the imported modules/libraries for reference.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import os.path
import xlrd
import xlwings as xw
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import re 
import datetime
    .
    .
    .
colC = ['' if x is None else x for x in colC]
colC = [ticker.replace(' USD', '').replace(' SWAP', '').replace(' CVR', 
'').replace('.USD', '') for ticker in colC]
colC = [ticker.split()[0] + " Options" if p.match(ticker) else ticker for 
ticker in colC]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `colC` is a iterable but `ticker` is one value of this `colC` iterable

Comment: `for ticker in colC` - it loops through the values in colC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ticker refers to each item in the list colC. The expressions are called "list comprehensions". Google that. Basically it's a for loop in a compact syntax

```
[ ...some expr... for ticker in colC]
  \           /   \                /
   inside loop     --- for loop ---
```

It's a bit difficult without test data but The first line:

```
colC = ['' if x is None else x for x in colC]
```

will substitute every occurrence of None with '' (empty str) in colC.

The second line will replace any occurence of `' USD', ' SWAP', ' CVR', '.USD'` with '' (empty str) in colC.

The third line looks like it will take the first word in ticker (colC item) and add the string `' Options'` if ticker matches the regex `p`. If not it will return ticker. For all items in colC.

Answer (score 0):

```
colC = [ticker.replace(' USD', '').replace(' SWAP', '').replace(' CVR', 
'   ').replace('.USD', '') for ticker in colC]
```

This line can be expanded like this

```
for ticker in colC:
     result = ticker.replace(' USD', '').replace(' SWAP', '').replace(' CVR', 
     '   ').replace('.USD', '')
     colC.append(result)
```

This for loop is used to iteate through each element in list colC. At every iteration ticker variable gets current element and at next iteration it gets next element. 
So ticker is just a variable used to iterate over the list. You can use any name instead of ticker. It will work.